# Excel Pivot Table impossible situation

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2016, pivot-table

I have a table that has a list of customers and some attributes, in the form of

> Customer | Purchased Amount | State | etc.

So far, so good. The issue is that our customers answered a poll and we tabulated the results. Basically we used this format

> Customer # | Attribute 1 | Attribute 2 | Attribute 3 |
>
> Customer 1 |     1       |      0      |      1      |
>
> Customer 2 |     0       |      0      |      0      |
>
> Customer 3 |     1       |      0      |      0      |

I've tried every possible way to create a Pivot Table around this (to pivot results of attributes with sales, states, etc.), but whenever I add more than one attribute, the 1 and 0 gets nested. Excel does not recognize them as the same label and it makes impossible to make any analysis.

[This is how it looks nested](https://i.stack.imgur.com/umhHn.png)

I know the ideal setup is to use just one column and add the attributes there, but in this case it is impossible because customers may have added one OR MORE attributes. That's why I did it in different columns.

Using Power Query to unpivot fusions all the attributes in one column but it only lefts the first one, the others get lost.

What is the right way to do this?

Comment: The way you tabulated your results is already a pivot table. Perhaps telling us what question you are trying to answer may allow us (or you) to come up with possible solutions.

Comment: Better share some Sample data as Screen Shot will help us the form of Input data!!